# Only overflow-x should be used not overflow-y

Tags: html, css, html-lists, overflow

Hi I'm Trying to use just overflow-x and not overflow-y

The structure is like

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Head1</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span>Head2</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Head3</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span>Head4</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span>Head5</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
         <span>Head6</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
     <li>
         <span>Head7</span>
        <ul>
            <li>feild1</li>
            <li>feild2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
#container {
  float: left;
  max-width: 234px;
  background-color: gray;
  max-height: 250px;
}
#container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  max-width: 194px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: auto;
}
#container > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Head1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head3</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head4</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head5</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head6</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head7</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The main div `#container` remains under a max width.
The ul should be overflowed horizontally not vertically

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2utguhm/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display the parent `ul` as `table-row` and the `list item` as `table-cell` and set `overflow-y` to `hidden`

```
#container{
    float: left;
    max-width: 234px;
    background-color: gray;
    max-height: 250px;
}

#parentul{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    max-width: 194px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    display:table-row;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#parentul>li{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/p2utguhm/7/)

Comment: Thanks mate, That did the trick.
But can you explain / give me link so that i can understand css better.

Comment: Try codecademy site. Also create a sample project, from that only you can achieve/learn more. Happy to Help You.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `overflow : auto;` from your css. 
"Auto overflow only gives the box the scroll bars it needs."

Add this

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

```css
#container {
  float: left;
  max-width: 234px;
  background-color: gray;
  max-height: 250px;
}
#container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  max-width: 194px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#container > ul > li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span>Head1</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head2</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head3</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head4</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head5</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head6</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span>Head7</span>
      <ul>
        <li>feild1</li>
        <li>feild2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Example horizontal scroll only: http://jsfiddle.net/p2utguhm/3/

Comment: I'm able to see the overflow-x but the contents are still not scrollable.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2utguhm/5/)

Comment: Because the overflow-x attribute was "SCROLL" so it will show scrollbar, or you can change to the attribuet to "AUTO" to hide the scrollbar, the scrollbar will show only when you resize the box.

Comment: the Head* should be visibile horizontally, no matter how many are there. So, to be clear, i need the horizontal scroll bar to scroll.